# TTY/Console Wallpaper Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, console, tty, wallpaper

How can I set a wallpaper for a TTY/console (also during boot) on Arch Linux like done on OpenSUSE? I think a Kernel recompile is needed?
[image: opensuse tty/console]

Comment: @l0b0 First it uses image instead of the boot messages and then if you press [ESC] it shows the image with the boot messages in front of it. After boot it is also behind the normal console/tty.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is fbcondecor ! here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fbsplash#Console_backgrounds

Oh, and you do need a patchd kernel.